# Output error, always 1, when trying to find absolute value of complex number

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct COMPLEX_T
{
    int real;
    int imaginary;
} complex_t;  

else if (choice == 3) {
        printf("\n\nEnter a and  b where a + ib is a complex number\n");
        printf("a = ");
        scanf("%d", &a.real);
        printf("b = ");
        scanf("%d", &a.imaginary);
        float sqr_sum = pow(a.real, 2) + pow(a.imaginary, 2);
        float abs = pow(sqr_sum, 1/2);
        printf("\n\nThe absolute value is: %.2f", abs);
      }
```

Here is a code snippet. I am trying to find the absolute value of a complex number. When I input two numbers the output is "1.00", no matter which two numbers I input.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `1/2` ==> `1.0/2` otherwise it's integer division which yields `0`...or, maybe better, use `sqrt()`

Comment: Don't you get a "else without if error" for that code? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @pmg I now realise that my answer is largely your comment. Do you want me to delete? But then you please make an answer. If it is OK with you I would extend my answer to use all of your contribution (with credits).

Answer (score 1):

`1/2` is integer division and zero.
Aything to the power of zero is one.

Convert either the `1` or the `2` (or both) to `double`

```
pow(x, 1.0/2);
pow(x, 1/(double)2);
```

Also `sqrt()` is used more often.

```
sqrt(x);
```

You might even want to change the previous line. Using `pow()` for integers is not recommended, among other things because of
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
For integers raised to the power of especially two, consider

```
float sqr_sum = a.real * a.real + a.imaginary * a.imaginary;
```

Comment: You editing your part into my answer (appreciated of course) let me forget my promise to attribute. Thanks for confirming that you are already happy. @pmg